# How to calculate delay of a packet AODV

Tags: ns2

I have a big trace file of AODV ns2 simulation. Packets have ids. How can I get the time at the source and the time at final destination (usually the sink) for a certain packet?

Comment: Example : The script "tess-Packets.awk" → » Saves a list = Packets-arrival-time.txt ... and prints Average delay « https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1rU_MFAEl1GCLMTJPLR3zbxPxkQQHkQ7T?usp=sharing .... `$ gawk tess-Packets.awk W.tr` : 3000 lines is printed out.

Comment: Ex 2 (AODV) : `$ gawk tess-Packets.awk guindy.tr` ( trace = 4.9MB) .... → → Packets-arrival-time.txt = 10,000 lines : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lQGYUBVwYLSBEuwWAwye9T7gnZFCpWrG/view?usp=sharing